# Flutter : How to send sms in background by api call?

Tags: api, flutter, push-notification, background, sms

How to send sms by api call when app isn't active. I write a code with firebase push notification where I try to call a function which send sms without user's interaction.

It's working when app is active, but it isn't working when app is inactive.

Here is my code-

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
  bool permissionsGranted = false;

//For Firebase Messaging
  String title1 = "";
  String body1 = "";

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestPermission();

    //For Firebase Push Notification

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message['notification']['title']");
        setState(() {
          title1 = message['notification']['title'];
          body1 = message['notification']['body'];
          // _showDialog();
        });
        sendOTPSmS("${message['notification']['title']}",
            "${message['notification']['body']}");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        sendOTPSmS("${message['notification']['title']}",
            "${message['notification']['body']}");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        sendOTPSmS("${message['notification']['title']}",
            "${message['notification']['body']}");
      },
    );
  }

  requestPermission() async {
    bool permission = await telephony.requestPhoneAndSmsPermissions;
    setState(() {
      permissionsGranted = permission;
    });
  }

//Send OTP MEssage
  sendOTPSmS(String number, String body) {
    final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
    telephony.sendSms(to: "$number", message: "$body");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Working in the background is not something very simple to do with dart, you will need some native code as described in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXuAzXY_KOo).

Answer (score 1):

Its not very difficult. You only need firebase FCM & background_sms packages.

1. Create an FCM background message handler.
2. Send a "data" message from FCM to the "myTopic".
   Below is a simple python code for sending FCM message from firebase_admin sdk:

   message = messaging.Message( data={'number': '1234567890', 'message': 'Hello there!'}, topic='myTopic')

   messaging.send(message)
3. Catch & parse the message. Send SMS with the help of background_sms package.

Here is the complete flutter demo:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:background_sms/background_sms.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> sms(String to, String msg) async {
  await BackgroundSms.sendMessage(phoneNumber: to, message: msg);
}

Future<void> _fcmBgHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  String num = message.data['number'];
  String msg = message.data['message'];
  if (num.isNotEmpty && msg.isNotEmpty) {
    await sms(num, msg);
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_fcmBgHandler);
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('myTopic');
}
```